# How to link an X11 program

Tags: c, linker, x11

I've got my first X11 program compiled, but cannot link it.  I'm on 64-bit Xubuntu 13.10, and I use the command line
gcc $(pkg-config x11) findXfonts.c -o findXfonts

It compiles okay, but every X* symbol I use shows up as undefined in the linker step.
The pkg-config idiom expands to simply -lX11

```
/*
 * Copyright 2014 Kevin O'Gorman <kogorman@gmail.com>.
 * Distributed under the GNU General Public License.
 *
 * This is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
 * it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
 * the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
 * (at your option) any later version.
 *
 * This is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 * but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 * MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
 * GNU General Public License for more details.
 *
 * You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
 * along with this program; if not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
 */

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char **fontlist;
  XFontStruct *returned_info;
  char *pattern="-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-";
  int nFonts;
  char *displayName;
  Display *display;
  FILE *ostream = stdout;
  int i, j, k;

  displayName = getenv("DISPLAY");        /* expect ":0.0", but YMMV */
  display = XOpenDisplay(displayName);
  fontlist = XListFontsWithInfo(display, pattern, 10000, &nFonts, &returned_info);

  for (i = 0; i < nFonts; i++) {
    fprintf(ostream, "\n%s\n", fontlist[i]);
    fprintf(ostream, "   first: %u/%u, last: %u/%u\n",
        returned_info[i].min_byte1, returned_info[i].min_char_or_byte2,
        returned_info[i].max_byte1, returned_info[i].max_char_or_byte2);
    for (j = 0; j < returned_info[i].n_properties; j++) {
      fprintf(ostream, "      %s: %ld\n", 
          XGetAtomName(display, returned_info[i].properties[j].name),
          returned_info[i].properties[j].card32);
    }
  }

  XFreeFontInfo(fontlist, returned_info, nFonts);
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: are you actually linking in the X .so files? Just because you're including the X headers means very little to the linker.

Comment: `gcc $(pkg-config x11 --cflags --libs) source.c -o whatever` should work fine: you only missed to specify what kind of "info" you want from `pkg-config`

Comment: Dang.  I knew that and thought I had done that.  Fortunately, I checked before answering snide.  However, when I fixed that, I get the linker error "/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lX11".  This seems odd, but I also notice there is absolutely no LD_LIBRARY_PATH (or whatever it's called) in my environment.  I'll have to see what to do about that.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
gcc $(pkg-config x11 --cflags) findXfonts.c -o findXfonts $(pkg-config x11 --libs)
```

Then read the manual page of pgk-config with:

```
man pkg-config
```

Answer (score 2):

It is false that

> The pkg-config idiom expands to simply -lX11

in fact if you try

```
echo $(pkg-config x11)
```

you obtain nothing. Instead

```
echo $(pkg-config x11  --cflags --libs)
```

outputs (on my system)

```
-lX11
```

which is what you want and all you need being everything correctly set up on your system in order to compile and develop X11 codes.

So, it should be enough you add `--cflags --libs` inside your `$(...)`.

Comment: Should, but isn't, due to other problem.  See comment to previous answer.

Comment: @4dummies LD_LIBRARY_PATH could be "void" as well, since there are some default library system path, e.g. /usr/lib and others: LD_LIBRARY_PATH it's "" on my system too, where I can compile it seemlessly. Then, the guess is: your x11 library is in a non-standard location (/opt/lib?). Try find! Or, `ldd executable` where Executable is a program linking to x11 for sure (say, xfontsel); then try `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/x11 gcc ...`. It's just a swift test, no a I-am-sure-of solution. I find it odd that `pkg-config` won't give you already all the correct needed flags.

Answer (score 0):

There were three problems.

First, I left off the --libs switch to pkg-config.  (The --cflags switch contributes nothing in this case).  I also had it in the wrong place in the command line.

Second, the linker could not find the X11 library.  I had to tell it which directory to look in.  Some folks use LD_LIBRARY_PATH for this, but since I have both 64- and 32-bit libraries, I don't want a single approach.

In the end, I made a Makefile, and end up with

```
gcc -Wall -ansi -g -m64 -c findXfonts.c
gcc findXfonts.o -m64 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lX11 -o findXfonts
```

Finally, once it compiled and linked, I discovered the "pattern" string had an extra hyphen ("-") at the end.  I removed it, and got a list of 1400+ fonts.